# Getting an simple value with Entity Framework Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a Stored Procedure and turns me an integer. I want to take and use that integer but get an error like:

> 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult1[System.Nullable1[System.Int32]]'
>   type object  couldn't assign to 'System.IConvertible'.

Here is my Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC prDetectMurderer(@carId INT)      
AS BEGIN      
SET NOCOUNT ON      
SELECT TOP 1 DriverId FROM EventTable       
WHERE CarId = @carId    
AND Damage = 'false'      
ORDER BY EventId DESC      
SET NOCOUNT OFF      
END
```

And my c# code:

```
int sofor = Convert.ToInt16(entity.prDetectMurderer(11));
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Did you import the stored procedure as a **Function**? See here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140774/getting-data-from-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework

Comment: Yes I imported the sp as prDetectMurderer() method with an integer parameter

Comment: And when you imported did you choose the return value of the procedure  to be **Scalar**?

Comment: And also instead of `int` use `var` like this: `var sofor = Convert.ToInt16(entity.prDetectMurderer(11));` or use `System.Nullable<int>` instead of `int`.

Comment: Based on the error, the Convert.ToInt16 method does not support the nullable type. The result is nullable because the stored procedure may not find any results that match.

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35832669/3572241 shows how to get an int from a stored procedure, using EF.